# Error creating communication site in Sharepoint Online via REST and Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to create a sharepoint online site collection based on the Communication site template,  as described by Microsoft here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/communication-site-creation-rest by using javascript on a page in a different sharepoint site

But, I keep getting a response of 403- although I am a tenant admin and so definitely have permission to create sites.
I am running the script below from a page at a url like companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/myTestSite/sitepages/RunSomeJS.aspx

I have tried specifying REST endpoint domain of both 
companyname.sharepoint.com
and
companyname-admin.sharepoint.com
but get the same error.

```
function DoRestCall(){      
    var body={'parameters':
    {
        "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Publishing.CommunicationSiteCreationRequest"},
        "AllowFileSharingForGuestUsers":false,
        "Classification":"MyTest Communication Site",
        "Description":"Here is my communication site",
        "SiteDesignId":"6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767",
        "Title":"MyTest Communication Site",
        "Url":"https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/testSiteName",            
        "lcid":1033
        }
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/_api/sitepages/create",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        headers:{
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        success: function () 
        {
            alert('CREATION REQUEST SUBMITTED');
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('failure:' + data.statusText );
        }
    });
}
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make couple of changes as below:

1) Change the metadata as below:

```
"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Publishing.PublishingSiteCreationRequest"},
```

2) You need to replace `parameters` to `request`

3) Modify the endpoint to create communication site as below:

```
url: "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/_api/sitepages/publishingsite/create",
```

3) Ensure that you are running the code from the root site(whose url is like `https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sitepages/RunSomeJS.aspx`) and you are the site collection admin of that root site.

You final code would be as below:

```
function DoRestCall(){      
    var body={'request':
    {
        "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Publishing.PublishingSiteCreationRequest"},
        "AllowFileSharingForGuestUsers":false,
        "Classification":"MyTest Communication Site",
        "Description":"Here is my communication site",
        "SiteDesignId":"6142d2a0-63a5-4ba0-aede-d9fefca2c767",
        "Title":"MyTest Communication Site",
        "Url":"https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/testSiteName",            
        "lcid":1033
        }
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/_api/sitepages/publishingsite/create",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        processData: false,
        headers:{
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(body),
        success: function () 
        {
            alert('CREATION REQUEST SUBMITTED');
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('failure:' + data.statusText );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hey @user3156, any luck ? I tried it in my tenant and it works in my tenant

Comment: Yes this does work for me! I also verified that it doesn't have to run in the root site collection of the tenant - I was able to run it on another site collection. Also, I'm told that their is a bug with the site creation API described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/communication-site-creation-rest - which will hopefully be resolved in the near future (there is now a note at that url explaining it)